# break line element not being properly displayed by a script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line code in a js file:

```
 "label: " + node.label + $('</br>') + "id: " + node.id + $('</br>') + "size: " + node.size
```

However,when I run it , it returns:

```
 label: node.label[object-object]id: node.id[object-object]size: node.size
```

The `<br>` tag is not rendering correctly. What's wrong?

That snippet of code comes from a sigma.js graph sample that generates tooltips on hover of a node.

Here is the rest of the code:

```
 sigma.canvas.hovers.def = function (node, context, settings) {
    var x,
        y,
        w,
        h,
        e,
        fontStyle = settings('hoverFontStyle') || settings('fontStyle'),
        prefix = settings('prefix') || '',
        size = node[prefix + 'size'],
        fontSize = (settings('labelSize') === 'fixed') ?
            settings('defaultLabelSize') :
            settings('labelSizeRatio') * size;

    // Label background:
    context.font = (fontStyle ? fontStyle + ' ' : '') +
        fontSize + 'px ' + (settings('hoverFont') || settings('font'));

    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = settings('labelHoverBGColor') === 'node' ?
        (node.color || settings('defaultNodeColor')) :
        settings('defaultHoverLabelBGColor');

    if (settings('labelHoverShadow')) {
        context.shadowOffsetX = 0;
        context.shadowOffsetY = 0;
        context.shadowBlur = 8;
        context.shadowColor = settings('labelHoverShadowColor');
    }

    if (typeof node.label === 'string') {
        x = Math.round(node[prefix + 'x'] - fontSize / 2 + 20);
        y = Math.round(node[prefix + 'y'] - fontSize / 40 - 80);
        w = Math.round(
            context.measureText("lable: " + node.label).width + fontSize / 2 + size + 7
        );
        h = Math.round(fontSize + 70);
        e = Math.round(fontSize / 20 + 1);

        context.moveTo(x, y + e);
        context.arcTo(x, y, x + e, y, e);
        context.lineTo(x + w, y);
        context.lineTo(x + w, y + h);
        context.lineTo(x + e, y + h);
        context.arcTo(x, y + h, x, y + h - e, e);
        context.lineTo(x, y + e);

        context.closePath();
        context.fill();

        context.shadowOffsetX = 0;
        context.shadowOffsetY = 0;
        context.shadowBlur = 0;
    }

    // Node border:
    if (settings('borderSize') > 0) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = settings('nodeBorderColor') === 'node' ?
            (node.color || settings('defaultNodeColor')) :
            settings('defaultNodeBorderColor');
        context.arc(
            node[prefix + 'x'],
            node[prefix + 'y'],
            size + settings('borderSize'),
            0,
            Math.PI * 2,
            true
        );
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
    }

    // Node:
    var nodeRenderer = sigma.canvas.nodes[node.type] || sigma.canvas.nodes.def;
    nodeRenderer(node, context, settings);

    // Display the label:
    if (typeof node.label === 'string') {
        context.fillStyle = (settings('labelHoverColor') === 'node') ?
            (node.color || settings('defaultNodeColor')) :
            settings('defaultLabelHoverColor');

        context.fillText(
        "label: " + node.label + "<br/>" + "id: " + node.id + "<br/>" + "size: " + node.size,

        Math.round(node[prefix + 'x'] + size + 10),
            Math.round(node[prefix + 'y'] - 60)
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use the jQuery object `$('</br>')` in a string. I'm not sure what your code is doing, but try this with just `<br />` (don't wrap it in $())

Comment: I want to show me label and id and size in separate line by using 'br' html tag .

Comment: @JohnRooney [HTML5 styling standards](https://github.com/mdo/code-guide) say you should use `<br>` with no trailing slash.

Answer (score 2):

`$('<br/>')` produces a DOM object for a `br` element. If you want to add a `br` element to a string you are building up, just use `"<br/>"`:

```
"label: " + node.label + "<br/>" + "id: " + node.id + "<br/>" + "size: " + node.size
```

As for why your output has "node.label" in it rather than some actual value, your guess is as good as mine because you haven't shown us enough of your code to figure that out.

Comment: I add all of code to question. my code is a part of sigma js graph sample. it generate tooltip of nodes.

Comment: Thank you. After looking at your code, I'm still not sure why your output has "node.label" in it (if it actually does), but have I answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

if @JLRishe's solution works i am happy. if not, you can try this:

```
"label: " + node.label + '\n' + "id: " + node.id + '\n' + "size: " + node.size
```

so `\n` instead of `<br/>`